# How to use SAMtool htslib library to read optional info fields

Tags: bioinformatics, samtools

I have a BAM file:

```
ERR174327.487900        99      chr9    80320323        60      101M    =       80320752        530     AGGGACATTGGTCCAAAAGGTTTTAATTAACCATACACCCTGCTCTACAAATCTAAAAAACTGTAGGACAGTATTTTGAGTCTCCAAGTATCCAGTGATAA   CCCFFFFFHHHHFIJJJJJJGIJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJIJIJJJJJIIJJJIJIJJJJJJJGICEHIHFHH=BFFADFFDCCCDCDDDCCCDADC@>ADC@   NM:i:0  AS:i:101        XS:i:0  RG:Z:group1
```

I need to read the optional fields `NM:i:0  AS:i:101        XS:i:0  RG:Z:group1` in my C++ code. I am able to use the `htslib` library to read everything but those optional fields.

The source file for the htsib library is [here](https://github.com/samtools/htslib/blob/develop/htslib/sam.h) on Github. Unfortunately, I am not able to find a function that can read those fields.

**Q:** How to read the optional fields with htslib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in bam.h

```
/*!
  @abstract       Retrieve data of a tag
  @param  b       pointer to an alignment struct
  @param  tag     two-character tag to be retrieved

  @return  pointer to the type and data. The first character is the
  type that can be 'iIsScCdfAZH'.
 */

 static inline uint8_t *bam_aux_get_core(bam1_t *b, const char tag[2]);
```